# How to create dbus message?

Tags: python, dbus

I am trying to create a dbus message format of signature aa(ss). What i tried to do so far is :

```
        dbus.Array([dbus.Array([dbus.Struct((dbus.String(u's'),dbus.String(u'ip_address=1.2.3.4')))]])
```

but this seems not working. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When calling a method with the signature `aa(ss)` from a Python program, this works as argument for me:

```
dbus.Array([dbus.Array([dbus.Struct((dbus.String(u'str1'), dbus.String(u'str2')), signature=None)], signature=dbus.Signature('(ss)'))], signature=dbus.Signature('a(ss)'))
```

Also, this shorter format worked as well:

```
[[dbus.Struct(["str1", "str2"])]]
```